# TreeSet and equals function

Tags: java, equals, comparator, treeset

There is a Java bean object which has implemented `equals` function based on certain criteria (Criteria A). I have a requirement to identify unique objects based on another criteria (Criteria B). Since the `equals` function uses criteria A, I can not use `HashSet`. So I thought of using `TreeSet` with my custom `Comparator` which is based on criteria B. My question is, Is it allowed to do like this? Any issues with this approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is some guide from Oracle Java:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a
>   set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be
>   consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface.
>   (See Comparable or Comparator for a
>   precise definition of consistent with
>   equals.) This is so because the Set
>   interface is defined in terms of the
>   equals operation, but a TreeSet
>   instance performs all key comparisons
>   using its compareTo (or compare)
>   method, so two keys that are deemed
>   equal by this method are, from the
>   standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even
>   if its ordering is inconsistent with
>   equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Set interface.

I think in terms of technical, no, you don't have any problems. But, in terms of coding, readability and maintainability, you have to be careful, because other people can misuse or misunderstand what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

If you perform search often and add elements rarely, consider keeping them in a `List` sorted by Criteria B and using [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them:

```
class BeanWrapper {

 ...

 public boolean equals(Object other) {
  return myBean.critB.equals(((Bean)other).critB);
 }

}
```

And put them in the set like that.